# android : Trouble populating listview with contacts

Tags: android, listview, logcat

I've looked around a lot on google and stackoverflow and finally wrote some code which I think should get the contacts into the listview as expected. But I always get this error. Can anyone help me ?

This is my Main class :

```
package com.shoaiblalich.pinchme;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class Main extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    populateContactList();
}




private void populateContactList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor cur = getContacts();
    String[] fields = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cur,fields,new int[] {android.R.id.text1});;
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);   

}




@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private Cursor getContacts() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String [] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    return managedQuery(uri,projection,selection,selectionArgs,sortOrder);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And this is what my logCat displays:

```
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.shoaiblalich.pinchme/com.shoaiblalich.pinchme.Main}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "LOCALIZED": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, display_name FROM view_contacts_restricted WHERE ((1)) ORDER BY display_nameCOLLATE LOCALIZED ASC
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2304)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "LOCALIZED": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, display_name FROM view_contacts_restricted WHERE ((1)) ORDER BY display_nameCOLLATE LOCALIZED ASC
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:385)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:417)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:360)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1826)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at com.shoaiblalich.pinchme.Main.getContacts(Main.java:51)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at com.shoaiblalich.pinchme.Main.populateContactList(Main.java:30)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at com.shoaiblalich.pinchme.Main.onCreate(Main.java:22)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5369)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
01-02 12:28:44.037: E/AndroidRuntime(8074):     ... 11 more
01-02 12:28:45.547: I/Process(8074): Sending signal. PID: 8074 SIG: 9
```

I'm really having a tough time trying to get the contacts into the listview. If my question is too confusing, can anyone just show me how to go about doing this from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error is very clear its a syntax error, space is missing after `display_name` in `ORDER BY display_nameCOLLATE LOCALIZED ASC`

replace as below

```
String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
```